# React Form Unit Testing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

*I'm new to react js and was trying to unit test my react form but i'm getting an error saying "Unable to find an element by: [data-testid="input-first-name"].
It would be of great help if someone can suggest something*

**AddUser.js**

- Here,i'm posting a small part of my code

```
return (
    <>
      {isLoggedIn === "true" ? (
        <div data-testid="user">
          <NavbarAdmin />
          <div className={styles.body}>
            <h2 className={styles.h2}>Add User</h2>
            <form className={styles.form}
            data-testid="filter-input-form">
              <div className={styles.formField}>
                <label
                  htmlFor="validationServer01"
                  style={{ marginLeft: "-131px", marginBottom: "0px" }}
                  className="form-label"
                >
                  First Name <span style={{ color: "#D22B2B" }}>*</span>
                </label>
                <input
                  style={inputStyle}
                  className="Form control lg is-invalid"
                  type="text"
                  name="FirstName"
                  placeholder="Enter your First-Name"
                  value={fname}
                  onBlur={() => fieldValidation("fname")}
                  onChange={(e) => {
                    setFName(e.target.value);
                  }}
                  data-testid="input-first-name"
                  required
                />
                <br />
                {fNameEmpty === true ? (
                  <div
                    className="invalid-feedback"
                    style={{
                      marginBottom: "15px",
                      marginTop: "-25px",
                      marginLeft: "-30px",
                    }}
                  >
                    Please Enter First Name!
                  </div>
                ) : (
                  ""
                )}
              </div>
              <button
                className={styles.btn}
                type="submit"
                onClick={handleClick}
                disabled={isDisabled}
                data-testid="add-users-button"
              >
                Add User
              </button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      ) : (
        ""
      )}
    </>
  );
```

**AddUser.test.js**

- This is the test case

```
import React from "react";
import AddUsers from "../Containers/User/AddUsers";
import {
  render,
  waitFor,
  screen,
  fireEvent,
  act,
  getByTestId

} from "@testing-library/react";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';

describe('AddUser component', () => {

    it('should render the component onto the screen', () => {
        render(<BrowserRouter><AddUsers show={true}/> </BrowserRouter>);
        expect(screen.getByTestId('input-first-name')).toBe("");
    });
```

**Error**
[Click here to see the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTTjM.png)
[I guess,this error is occuring because of the ternary operator]

Comment: What is the name of the file? "AddUser" or "AddUsers? Typo in the code maybe?

Comment: I think it relates to the first condition in the user component... You should assign `true` to `isLoggedIn` for showing the form and its inputs.

Comment: @IgorGonak File name is "AddUsers"

Comment: @AbdelrhmanArnos Okk, but is there any way to change the value of isLoggedIn inside the test case..because in my project this value depends upon the Login component..by default it is false.